# jQuery - enable form through ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am using backbone.js and I have an event attached to a button that displays a form attached to the selected element. After the new form is submitted, it replaces text on the DOM.

The problem is that the next click on the original button does not launch the menu. I'm not sure what's going on.

```
          events: {
        'click .editUser': 'edit',
        // 'click #editPerson': 'editPerson',
        'click .deleteUser': 'remove'
    },

    edit: function () {
        menuBar = $("#editPerson"); ///this is my new input form
        console.log(this.model);
        var model = (this.model);
        console.log(model);

        $(this.el).css("background-color", function (index){
            return "rgba(54,42,64, .9)";
        });
        $(".contact-container").css("margin", function (index){
            return "0 5px 100px 0 ";
        })
        $(this.el).append(menuBar);
        console.log($(this.el));
        menuBar.show();


        $("#editPerson").on('submit', function() {
            console.log("hoook");
            var name = $(".edit1").val();
            var address = $(".edit2").val();
            var telephone = $(".edit3").val();
            var email = $(".edit4").val();

            model.set({name: name});
            model.set({address: address});
            model.set({tel: telephone});
            model.set({email: email});
            // $(":button").removeAttr("disabled");
            return false;
        });

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you appending the #editPerson to $el if it's already in the DOM? What that does is take the node from the DOM and append it inside your $el. That has a bad smell! The next time your view looks for this node, it won't find it if you have removed the previous view, as it's no longer in the DOM.

If #editPerson is just a form's template, you can retrieve the HTML and append it to your view:

```
this.$el.append($("#editPerson").html())
```

(this.$el is equivalent to $(this.el) and is 'faster' because the object already exists, when you create your Backbone View, Backbone will assign a variable this.$el = $(this.el) for convenience)

Then, you can add the 'submit #editPerson': 'onSubmit' key in your events hash and copy your handler code to a new onSubmit function within the View. No need to do the binding manually because Backbone will 'notice' (that's not really how it works, Backbone isn't watching the DOM) that a new element has been added to your view and the event will just work.